# Where does VS2010 store modified keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, menu, keyboard-shortcuts

I have this strange behaviour in VS2010 where any modifications I make to keyboard shortcuts or the text for top-level menu items (File, Edit, View, ...) are reset to their default values the next time I restart VS. I suspect that one or more of the add-ins I've installed could be the culprit. So far though, I have had no success in stopping this very annoying behaviour, so I'm desperate for any tips.

VS 2010 Professional RTM

Add-Ins that might be responsible:

- Red Gate .Net Reflector
- DevExpress Refactor! 10.1 (with DXCore, CodeRush Express)
- VisualSVN 2.0

Any ideas?

Comment: Could be a long shot, but I've seen this happen with other applications (e.g. 7-zip, VLC) where the settings don't hold unless I launch the application as an Administrator. Could it be UAC holding you back?

Comment: @Cory: Good idea, but unfortunately no, that wasn't it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MSDN:

> Several pre-defined keyboard shortcut collections are included in Visual Studio. You can change the keyboard shortcuts for most commands, and your changes are automatically saved in your active settings file.

I'm not sure where that is in 2010, but in 2008 it was something like `<path to your profile>\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings`.

Comment: Yes, of course, CurrentSettings. Nasty file, that. Compared two copies, one with my change, one after restarting VS (so without changes). But the only difference is that the one has the lines which cause the modification (<modify Cmd=... etc), the other doesn't. No clue there as to *why* the change is lost. Oh, well...

Comment: I cannot find any information about key shortcuts in `CurrentSettings.vssettings` file. I propose that this is not the answer. The question is still opened.

Answer (score 2):

While Cory's answer was strictly correct as to my question title (which is why I've marked it as the accepted answer), it didn't help me find the cause of the problem I described.

In the meantime, though, I've installed VS on a fresh system and then added the extras one by one - and discovered that it was Red Gate .Net Reflector add-in which was causing the erratic behaviour. Since I only rarely used the add-in and Reflector can easily be run stand-alone, I solved my problem by removing the add-in.